# How to implement relationship to the same table without using primary key fields?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table like

```
Groups(Base):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  code = Column(Integer, index=True)
  parent_code = Column(Integer, index=True)
```

I need to add children to my model, using join on parent_code=code.

I have found example in official SQL Alchemy docs:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/11/orm/self_referential.html
But the examples always use primary keys to get child rows without strict join condition.

I tried to add:

```
  children = relationship(Groups, 
primaryjoin='Groups.code=Groups.parent_code', uselist=True)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work how? Did you get an error, or did it misbehave?

Comment: Oh, I found an error ('=' vs '==' in join statement)
Now it looks so:

```children = relationship(Groups, 
primaryjoin=='Groups.code=Groups.parent_code', uselist=True)```

Now I have another problem. When I get full table with children, alchemy make a separate request for each row go get it's children. Is it possible to get and cache full table with children with one request (may be during initializing)?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `primaryjoin='Groups.code==Groups.parent_code'` :). You're going to run into using remote / foreign next, so check out: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#creating-custom-foreign-conditions

Comment: I add foreing key and now it works. But....
Now I have another problem. When I get full table with children, alchemy make a separate request for each row go get it's children. Is it possible to get and cache full table with children with one request (may be during initializing)?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes, if you're fetching to a certain depth in your tree, but not the entire tree.

Comment: Yes, I need just single step hierarchy.